# Anyway to increase twitter mining speed?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am conducting a tweepy mining operation, but noticed it takes quite a while to get a substantial number of tweets. A rough estimate would be 3000 tweets in about 3-4 hours - I am aiming for 1 million in two days. Similar queries suggested it could "just be your machine," but I was hoping for a more specific answer.

Would I be able to speed things up if I used some advanced server hosing service? Sorry, do not have a computer science background. Below is my code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('python2.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print(Error)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#happy'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need only the "new" tweets or also the old ones are good?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, I actually needed the old tweets more so, but didn't realize my stream function was getting only a live feed. I implemented a variation of your solution below and am getting excellent results. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad to help you, if you are in trouble, feel free to contact me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Stream function, so let's say that you are getting the real-time tweets with hashtag #happy. The rapidity with which you can get the data  depends also on how many people are tweeting with this hashtag at the moment. 
If I understood well from your question, you are going to getting tweets for some analysis. If yes, I think that you can use old tweets. 
To do this, you can follow two different ways:

1. Use tweepy api (not streaming)
2. Use [GetOldTweets-python](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python) library

I suggest you to use the second one because permits to get tweets without rate-limits.

Following there is an example to do what you have tried to do in your question with GetOldTweets-python library:

```
tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('#happy').setSince("2016-05-01").setMaxTweets(3000)
tweets = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)

for idx, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    data[idx] = tweet.text

with open('python2.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

With this code, I got 3000 tweets with hashtag #happy in 0:02:58.617514.

[Here](https://github.com/giordano91/twitter_scripts/tree/master/getTweetsWithHashtag), you can find a complete and working example.

Please, feel free to contact me for clarifications.

Let me know.